# Hibernate cascade deleting doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I have 3 entity: 'Person', 'Document', 'PersonDocument' which related as following:

```
class Person {
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<PersonDocument> personDocuments;
}

class Document {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document")
    Set<PersonDocument> personDocuments;
}

@IdClass(PersonDocumentPK.class)
public class PersonDocument {
    @Id
    private Person person;
    @Id
    private Document document;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Provider provider;
}

public class PersonDocumentPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_guid")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documents_guid")
    private Document document;
}
```

In my code I am trying to delete some records from `Person#personDocuments` and add new records. I am doing it like:

```
Iterator it = person.getPersonDocuments().iterator();
PersonDocument pd = it.next();
if (some logic) it.remove();
...
person.getPersonDocuments().addAll(new set of values);
```

In result removed `personDocuments` have disappeard, but related `documents` remained on database. Why is so?

Answer (score 1):

Cascade operations doesn't work like that.

When you use the `@Cascade` annotation, operations made in the parent will cascade to child assossiations depending on the cascade type.

As your class is annotated with `CascadeType.ALL`, all operations **made in the parent class** will cascade to the childs.

So, for the remove to work, you would need to call `entityManager.remove(person)`, and then the persistence provider would call the remove in the childs too.

That being said, change your code to somethng like that:

```
Iterator it = person.getPersonDocuments().iterator();
PersonDocument pd = it.next();
if (some logic)  {
   it.remove();
   em.remove(pd); // No problem to call in the loop because it will call the database only on commit or flush
}
...

person.getPersonDocuments().addAll(new set of values);
```

Answer (score 0):

try **CascadeType.DELETE**  instead of **CascadeType.ALL**

@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})

Comment: In this case I am getting exception: `identifier of an instance of model.entity.PersonDocument was altered from model.entity.PersonDocumentPK@f224a1f1 to model.entity.PersonDocumentPK@de57b5f`

Comment: you can see mkyoung exemple https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/                                                              and you can also make cascad delete from mysqlWorkbech directly